# Show/Hide columns based on dropdown selection

Tags: column, dropdown

When adding a document I want to show or hide colums based on a dropdown selection. In this case, the value of "Document type" is leading.

If a Travel Document (Column name "Travel Documents") is selected another column ("Employee") should become visible.

Therefore I've created following code with help from StackExchange:

```
<script src="/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"
$(document).ready(function(){

//Define which columns to show/hide by default
$('nobr:contains("Employee")').closest('tr').hide();

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
$("select[title='Document type']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Document type']").val() == "Travel Documents") {
$('nobr:contains("Employee")').closest('tr').show();
else if($("select[title='Document type']").val() != "Travel Documents"){
$('nobr:contains("Employee")').closest('tr').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

For some reason it does not work at all and the Employee dropdown is Always shown. When I delete the next part:

```
else if($("select[title='Document type']").val() != "Travel Documents"){
$('nobr:contains("Employee")').closest('tr').hide();
```

the Employee dropdown is hidden, but I can't get it back with selecting the right Document type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which SharePoint Version you are using ? The HTML code for 2010 and 2013 is different and the above  approach does not works in SP2013

Comment: So if `Travel Document` is selected in the `Document Type` column, the `Employee` column should appear. Else, it should be hidden?

Comment: @Akarsh Gupta: I'm using 2013, so that's probably were the problem lies...

Comment: @Kaylee Chatham: You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use, and it works. I've adjusted the code for your columns. You can also add additional columns that should be hidden, unless `Travel Documents` is selected, as well.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JQUERY REFERENCE URL"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckDropdown(Drop_Column,Hide_Column)
{
var DropDownColumn=$("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']");

//Value that should be selected in the drop down
if ($("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']option:selected").text() == "Travel Document")
{
HideColumn(Hide_Column,"False");
} 
else
{
HideColumn(Hide_Column,"True");

} 

}
function HideColumn(Column,IsHide)
{    
    if(IsHide=="True")
    {  
        $('nobr:contains("'+Column+'")').closest('tr').hide();
    }
    else
    { 
        $('nobr:contains("'+Column+'")').closest('tr').show();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

//  Hide fields that are used for the selected item. 
    var DocTypeField = $("select[title='Document Type']");

    CheckDropdown("Document Type", "Employee Name")
//  CheckDropdown("Document Type", "Other Column")
//  etc.


// DocumentType Field change event - show fields for travel docs
    DocTypeField.change(function() {
        var val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();// Text of DocType field

            if (val == "Travel Document")
            {
                HideColumn("Employee Name","False");
//              HideColumn("Other Column","False");
//              ect.
            } 
            else
            {
                HideColumn("Employee Name","True");
//              HideColumn("Other Column","True");
//              etc.
            }
            });

});



</script>
```

Comment: It seems to me the DocTypeField.change function is not working. As a simple test I've added an alert behind var val = $(this).find("option:selected").text(); and I never get the alert. Therefore it seems it stops there somewhere.

Comment: Try it now? It looks like I switched a couple fields accidentally. Edits made.

Comment: For some reason it still won't work. It seems the DocTypeField.change(function() { still doesn't work. up until this code it seems to work, nothing is triggered after it.  Just for me to understand the code better: How does this code work: DropDownColumn=$("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']");
How does it know to look at the "Document type" column? Is it via the "+Drop_Column+"? Maybe some more understanding will help me getting the last bits...

Comment: I think I now where it goes wrong, unfortunately I don't have the solution. With this code: var test2=$("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']option:selected").text();
alert(test2); it should return the value in the dropdown, however it shows an empty field. It already shows the alert before the page has been loaded completely (before I actually see the dropdowns). I've added the code after the $(document).ready(function(){, so I don't see why it does what it does... $(window).load(function() { doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [SPUtility.js](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility). See the below code, Not tested it but it should work you can modify it according to your column name. Please do not forget to include SPUtility.js as reference on your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Get a single select dropdown field
var TravelDocField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Travel Documents');

// create a function to show or hide Employee based on Travel Document's value
var showOrHideField = function() {
    var TravelDocFieldValue = TravelDocField.GetValue();
    // Hide the City field if the selected value is Other
    if(TravelDocFieldValue === 'Other') {
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Employee Name');
    }
    else {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Employee Name');
    }
};

// run at startup (for New form)
showOrHideField();

// make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
$(TravelDocField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't get it to work for some reason. I've changed the code to match my column, however some things don't make sense to me (my lack of experience I assume). I think the TravelDocField should be "Document type" (name of the column in which I can select "Travel Documents". However I don't see where the code then looks at the "Travel Documents" value?  Employee name should be Employee (as this is the column name containing the names of the employees).

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with SPUtility not loading. As I try this code: $(window).load(function () 
SPUtility.HideSPField('Employee');
});
It won't hide the column either. If I replace it with a simple alert(); it will show the alert. Minimal Download Strategy has been deactivated as I understood this may cause issues with SPUtility.

Comment: Can you please check in develepor's tool by pressing F12, then go to sources and check is SPUtilty is loaded or not. Also Check your console for any errors. As i have used this approach for lots of places and it works good.

Comment: I will check, again thank you for your help. Does it matter which version of jquery I use? At the moment I have a folder files which includes jquery-1.3.2.min.js, my reference url is <script language="javascript" src="../../files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: The JQuery version is fine, I cannot say about the reference path. Please check in Console and Sources.

Comment: Unfortuantely I can't use the console from Chrome (for some reason it's blocked at work) and I'm not to familiar with the IE one. I do however see a service jquery-1.3.2.min.js running. It seems it's working, because when i add this line: HideColumn("Employee","True"); after $(document).ready(function(){ the dropdown "employee" is hidden. If the service wasn't running HideColumn should not work I guess?

Comment: That's Correct. Please right click and check View source. All the JS files which are loaded should come there.

Comment: Finally I was able to check it with Chrome as well, the script is running, however I already expected that part :)

Comment: is everything working now ?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I'm still stuck at the same problem.  See my earlier comment from the 22nd. The compare function does not seems to get a value from the dropdown. I've tried several codes (found on the internet), but none of them return a value of the dropdown selection.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that my dropdowns are created from a document library, and all of them are lookup lists?

Comment: Check the internal name of the field

Comment: This code: ***CheckDropdown("Document Type", "Employee")*** seems to work perfect, this will hide the dropdown Employee, so the Function CheckDropdown(Drop_Column,Hide_Column) is OK. The only problem I keep having is the compare between the selected value and the value "Travel Documents". if I do this: if ($("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']option:selected").text() == "Travel Documents" the dropdown is still hidden, if I do if ($("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']option:selected").text() == "" the dropdown is visible again. Therefore it seems it always receives an empty value

Comment: BTW, The internal id is Document%5Fx0020%5Ftype.

Comment: I've tried to add this code:        $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#TEST').change(function(e){
       alert("A");
    });
    
    $('#TEST').trigger('change');
}); And added a column TEST to my editform. Also this does not trigger an alert, I really don't know why anymore?

Comment: is 'Test' the id of control in your form ?

Comment: Test is the name of the column I've made (without any lookups), this is also the internal name (Field=TEST). It has 3 manually entered choices to choose from. This is all in the EditForm.ASPX.

Comment: Column names and id's are not same. Jquery with "#" takes the id of the control. As of now your control will be getting null hence any event related to that control is not generating.

Comment: I know, however this code: $(document).ready(function(){

    $(":input[title='TEST']").change(function(e){
    
    var A = $(":input[title='TEST']").parent().parent().filter(":selected").text();
    alert(A);
    });
    
    $('#TESTDME').trigger('change');
});
 gives an alert, however it's not showing anything. It does however trigger on a change in the TEST dropdown. Therefore the #TEST seems to be ok

Answer (score 0):

@Akarsh I have it working now with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
CheckDropdown("Document Type", "Employee")
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$(":input[title='Document Type']").change(function(e){
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == "10")
        {
            HideColumn("Employee","False");
        } 
else
        {
            HideColumn("Employee","True");
        }

});

$('#Document Type').trigger('change');
});


function HideColumn(Column,IsHide)
{    
if(IsHide=="True")
{  
    $('nobr:contains("'+Column+'")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{ 
    $('nobr:contains("'+Column+'")').closest('tr').show();
}
}   


function CheckDropdown(Drop_Column,Hide_Column)
{
var DropDownColumn=$("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']");

//Value that should be selected in the drop down
if ($("select[title='"+Drop_Column+"']option:selected").text() == "10")
{
HideColumn(Hide_Column,"False");
} 
else
{
HideColumn(Hide_Column,"True");
} 
}

</script>
```

As you can see I've used several examples and mixed them a little, I will check your code again.

The problem seems to be caused by activating "Require that this column contains information" causes the .change function not to work. At this point I have no idea why, however I'm sure the answer can be found on StackExchange somewhere :)

Thank you for all your help